# Thymeleaf problems css?

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using this library [thymeleaf-layout-dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect#decorators-and-fragments)

my layout dialect....

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
          <title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">NextInfo</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../resources/css/animate.css" th:href="@{'resources/css/animate.css'}"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../resources/css/semantic.min.css" th:href="@{'resources/css/semantic.min.css'}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui stackable blue inverted menu">
              <a class="right item ">
                    <i class="home icon"></i>
                    Inicio
                  </a>
                 <a class="item">
                    <i class="phone icon"></i>
                    Telefones
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                    <i class="mail Outline icon"></i>
                    Email
                  </a>
                  <a class="item">
                    <i class="chat icon"></i>
                    Suporte
                  </a>
                   <div class="ui category search item" style="margin-right:40px">
                    <div class="ui transparent icon input">
                      <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder=" pesquisar ..." />
                      <i class="search link icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="results"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header" layout:fragment="header"></div>
        <div id="content" layout:fragment="content"></div>
        <div id="footer" layout:fragment="footer"></div>
        <script src="../../../resources/js/jquery.min.js" data-th-src="@{resources/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="../../../resources/js/semantic.min.js" data-th-src="@{resources/js/semantic.min.js}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I created a layout as shown in the link

My home controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ={"/","/home"})
public class Principal {

private final static String URLINICIAL = "index";

@RequestMapping(value ={"/","/home"} ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String requisicaoPadrao() {
    return URLINICIAL;
}
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/testes", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public <T> Object testes() {
    return null;
}
}
```

index.html

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"  layout:decorator="/templates/layouts/default">
  <head>

  </head>
<body>
 <div layout:fragment="header"><h1>index</h1></div>
 <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**creating a new view**

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"  layout:decorator="/templates/layouts/default">
  <head>
    <title>testPage</title>
  </head>
<body>
<h1>teste</h1>
     <div layout:fragment="header"><h1>testPage</h1></div>
     <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**new controller** 
**I need @RequestMapping annotation above the class.**

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class TestController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String index(){
            return "testpage";
        }

    }
```

As you can see it does not work ....
How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve just by changing this 
`<script src="../../../resources/js/jquery.min.js" data-th-src="@{resources/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>`

for

```
<script src="/web/resources/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I did not used the specific tags thymeleaf