# Why am I getting: Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

Hi we have a problem that in 1 of 50 cases we are getting the following error message in the browser log:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.    jQueryDetection https://localhost:8443/my-app/js/bootstrap.min.js:6    <anonymous> https://localhost:8443/my-app/js/bootstrap.min.js:6    <anonymous> https://localhost:8443/my-app/js/bootstrap.min.js:6    <anonymous> https://localhost:8443/my-app/js/bootstrap.min.js:6
```

and in our head-section of our html file we have the following:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link data-th-href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">
    <link data-th-href="@{/css/default-style.css}"
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">
    <script data-th-src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script data-th-src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    </head>
```

I have absolutely no idea what might causing this. I could only find similar issues where the solution was to load jquery before bootstrap... I would say I am doing this and this happens only in rare cases. Any ideas on this?

Comment: In that case, check the network tab of your browser's developer tools, Maybe for some reason the request fails. Also, can you please show the rendered HTML result from the browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf problems css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553302/thymeleaf-problems-css)

Comment: Change `data-th-src` to just `src` and put the path in.  Seems a "common" issue with data-th-src/data-th-href that they may not load in order.

Comment: thx. I will try. But since it occurs rarely and is hard to reproduce it might take some time until I can say if it worked or not.

Comment: never expected thymeleaf to be the cause...